# Area of a right trapezoid with bases $15$ and $8$, and height $9$

Tags: education, area

[image: Find the area.]

I can't figure out how they got that.
I got 1080, they got 103.5.
How???

Comment: How did you find $1080$ ?

Comment: I multiplied 15 by 9, then that by 8

Comment: What is the rationale behind multiplying these three numbers ??

Comment: I got 103.5 too. How on earth did you get 1080? (You can put it inside a $9\times 15$ rectangle, so it must be less than 135)

Comment: I thought that was how you did it

Comment: If you duplicate the trapezoid, you can form a rectangle with both. Figure out its area.

Comment: $15\ \mathrm m \times 9\ \mathrm m\times 8 \mathrm m = 1080\ \mathrm m^3,$ not $\mathrm m^2,$ so it's not even the correct units.

Comment: ooohhhh ok thank you!

Comment: Just as a sanity check, it should be obvious that the shape fits inside a $9\times 15$ rectangle, so the area cannot be more than $9\times 15 \mathrm m^2.$

Comment: @DavidK: do you expect the OP to understand dimensional analysis ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid#Area

Comment: @YvesDaoust One doesn't have to completely grok dimensional analysis to be aware how to multiply units. At least it's a hint.

Comment: Considering that the angle between the sides of length $15$ and $9$ isn't marked as a *right* angle (nor are the top and bottom otherwise marked as *parallel*), we don't know *for sure* that the figure is a trapezoid. Consequently, the area cannot be determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :** area of Trapezoid  is calculated by

$$ \frac{base_a + base_b}{2} \cdot  height   $$

Answer (score 0):

As has been explained in comments, your formula doesn't work. Instead, split it up into two shapes. You have two shapes, a $7\times 9$ right-angled triangle, and an $8\times 9$ rectangle. Calculate their areas and the area of the trapezium is their sum.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Divide it into these polygons and determinate the areas separately. You might need to use the Pythagorean theorem.

[image]

If not, you might want to use the formula for the [area of trapezoides](https://www.mathopenref.com/trapezoidareaderive.html):

$$\text{Area}=\frac{\text{base1}+\text{base2}}{2}·\text{height}$$